# What is the meaning of "all other handles to the deleted key" in the documentation of ZwDeleteKey / NtDeleteKey function

Tags: winapi

Quoted from the documentation of [ZwDeleteKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwdeletekey) function at the *Remarks* section,

> A call to **ZwDeleteKey** causes the handle that is specified in the
>   *KeyHandle* parameter—and **all other handles to the deleted key**—to become invalid. After a call to **ZwDeleteKey** invalidates the key
>   handles, you must call **ZwClose** to close the key handles.

In fact, ZwDeleteKey() can only delete the a key that does not have any subkeys. Therefore, the phrase **"all other handles to the deleted key"** definitely does not refer to **handles of subkeys** of the key.

My question is what does the phrase **"all other handles to the deleted key"** refers to? Handles of what?

Comment: handles of this key. not only you can have opened handle to key.

Comment: Oops, I see, thank you. So why not put your words as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means other handles that may be open to the same key that is being deleted.  A given key can have multiple open handles referring to it (just like files and other kernel objects can).